# Require a local HTML document with Expo

Tags: react-native, webpack, requirejs, expo

I want to use the new Expo Print functionality with a local HTML document:

```
import { Print } from 'expo';

const printDocument = require('../../../assets/printouts/document.html');
console.log(printDocument);
Print.printAsync({ html: printDocument });
```

When I run this with Expo, I get an error and I can see that `printDocument` is equal to an integer, not a string corresponding to the HTML document I’m trying to import.

On the other hand, if I try just this in React, where I use Webpack with the `html-loader` plugin:

```
const printDocument = require('../../../assets/printouts/document.html');
console.log(printDocument);
```

Then `printDocument` IS a string corresponding to the HTML document as expected.

So my conclusion is I need to configure Expo in some way to import HTML documents into Javascript strings the way `html-loader` does with Webpack.  Any ideas how? Thanks.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @Raptor Added now